# How to install iPad App Store downloads after being deleted?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

After deleting several applications I downloaded from App Store, I don't seem to be able to download them a second time as there is no Install button. Is this normal? Are they lost forever?

Answer (score 1):

Once you purchase or download a free app you will see a 'cloud' icon with a down arrow next to the apps name in the App Store. This identifies that you've previously purchased the app. Just tap on that and it will download again free of charge. Alternatively you can click on the App Store > Updates and there will be a Purchased button at the top. Tap on that a list of all the apps you've downloaded previously will display